Sticks and stones for extended objects
Suppose that we have a circle around which $L$ buckets are arranged. We have $k$ balls to distribute among the buckets and each bucket can contain at most one ball. For the purpose of this discussion suppose that $k\ll L$, something along the lines of $k=10$ and $L=100$.
Now fix an integer $0<N<k$. My task is to count the number of ways that the $k$ balls can be arranged such that they are organized into $N$ non-adjacent clusters of filled buckets.
For example, take the case $N=1$. In this case there is a single cluster, so all of the balls occupy a set of $k$ consecutive boxes on the circle. There are $L$ choices of such a region, so the answer in this case is $L$.
The next case I've worked out is $N=2$. (EDIT: What I've written here for $N=2$ is incorrect. See the selected answer below for a correction.) In this case, we suppose that the first cluster has size $n_{1}$ and the second has size $n_{2}$. The first cluster can be inserted in $L$ places, after which the second has $L-n_{1}-2$ possible locations. Moreover if $n_{1}=n_{2}$ we need to account for the fact that the regions are identical and divide by two. The result in this case is then given by the sum
$$\sum_{n_{1}=1}^{k}\sum_{n_{2}=1}^{n_{1}}\frac{\delta(k-n_{1}-n_{2})}{1+\delta(n_{1}-n_{2})}L(L-n_{1}-2)$$
This is as far as I've gotten because things seem to get trickier for $N=3$. In this case once you pick $n_{1}$ and $n_{2}$, the possible locations of the third cluster are constrained by how close the first and second clusters are to one another. This correlation seems to make things trickier so I am looking for new ideas about how to proceed.

Use the letter $B$ for buckets containing a ball and $E$ for empty
buckets and mark clusters with $C$. There are four cases taking
wrap-around into account, first,
$$\sum_{q\ge 1} \left[ \frac{B}{1-B} \frac{E}{1-E}\right]^q C^q$$
second,
$$\frac{E}{1-E}
\sum_{q\ge 1} \left[ \frac{B}{1-B} \frac{E}{1-E}\right]^q C^q$$
third,
$$\sum_{q\ge 1} \left[ \frac{B}{1-B} \frac{E}{1-E}\right]^q C^q
\frac{B}{1-B}$$
and fourth,
$$\frac{E}{1-E}
\sum_{q\ge 1} \left[ \frac{B}{1-B} \frac{E}{1-E}\right]^q C^q
\frac{B}{1-B} C.$$
Here we have skipped the case of all buckets being filled or all
buckets being empty. We seek $N$ clusters so we extract the coeffcient
on $C^N$ to get first,
$$\frac{B^N}{(1-B)^N}\frac{E^N}{(1-E)^N}$$
second,
$$\frac{E}{1-E} \frac{B^N}{(1-B)^N}\frac{E^N}{(1-E)^N}$$
third,
$$\frac{B^N}{(1-B)^N}\frac{E^N}{(1-E)^N} \frac{B}{1-B}$$
and fourth
$$\frac{E}{1-E} \frac{B^{N-1}}{(1-B)^{N-1}}
\frac{E^{N-1}}{(1-E)^{N-1}} \frac{B}{1-B}.$$
Add these to get
$$(2-B-E)\frac{B^N}{(1-B)^{N+1}}\frac{E^N}{(1-E)^{N+1}}.$$
We are interested in the coefficient on $B^k E^{L-k}$ so we get three
pieces, first
$$2 [B^{k-N}] \frac{1}{(1-B)^{N+1}}
[E^{L-k-N}] \frac{1}{(1-E)^{N+1}}
= 2 {k\choose N} {L-k\choose N}$$
second,
$$[B^{k-N-1}] \frac{1}{(1-B)^{N+1}}
[E^{L-k-N}] \frac{1}{(1-E)^{N+1}}
= {k-1\choose N} {L-k\choose N}$$
and third,
$$[B^{k-N}] \frac{1}{(1-B)^{N+1}}
[E^{L-k-N-1}] \frac{1}{(1-E)^{N+1}}
= {k\choose N} {L-k-1\choose N}.$$
This yields the following closed form for $N\ge 2$,
$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
2 {k\choose N} {L-k\choose N}
- {k-1\choose N} {L-k\choose N}
- {k\choose N} {L-k-1\choose N}.}$$
The formula for $N=2$ would appear to be
$$\frac{1}{2} L \sum_{n_1=1}^{L-3}
\sum_{n_2=1}^{L-n_1-2} \delta(k-n_1-n_2) (L-n_1-1-n_2).$$
Commentary,  as  per  request. First  of  all,  the
binomial coefficients  are special and  always evaluate
to zero  when the  upper index is  less than  the lower
one, in  particular when  the former goes  negative. As
for the construction, we  take the circular arrangement
of buckets and turn it  into a line, opening the circle
at the top, say. The right end of the line wraps around
to connect to the left.   We then classify the possible
configurations  according to  the  first  and the  last
elements, giving  four possibilities, $BE$,  $EE$, $BB$
and $EB.$  The case  $BB$ is  special because  the last
block of $B$s connects to the first one by wrap-around,
giving  one  block that  contributes  to  the $N$  runs
rather  than  two.   The  generating  functions  simply
produce  all possible  strings consisting  of $B$s  and
$E$s except for all buckets  full or all buckets empty,
which do not enter into  the count anyway. Finally note
that
$$\frac{B}{1-B} \frac{E}{1-E}
= (B + BB + BBB + \cdots) (E + EE + EEE + \cdots)
\\ = BE + BEE + BBE + BBBE + BBEE + BEEE + \cdots$$
so  this  generating  function represents  exactly  one
block  of contiguous  filled buckets  followed by  some
number of  empty ones.  The assignments to  all buckets
are  sequences  of these  blocks.  When  there are  $q$
blocks we get the generating function
$$\left[ \frac{B}{1-B} \frac{E}{1-E}\right]^q.$$

Thanks so much for the detailed answer, I now see what I had for $N=2$ was wrong as well! I've done some numerical tests which all agree with what you have so I believe this is correct, but I don't understand your reasoning about the "four cases". Could you explain how you arrive at, e.g., the expression for the first case? I don't understand the meaning of terms like B/(1-B) .

I've added some commentary.

Incredibly helpful answers, thanks very much.
